# why one bteq script works, but not the other

Tags: shell, scripting

Below are two similar codes, why the first one is working but not the 2nd one please? Can anyone please explain the usage of curly brackets after the round brackets?

```
$ vi varoutput.bt
query_td () {
bteq << EOBTQ |grep '^>' |sed -e "s/^>//"
.LOGON TDPROD/userid,pass;
select top 3  '>'||t.cal_dt from rldmprod_v.cal_dt t where t.cal_dt =    current_date;
.LOGOFF;
.QUIT;
EOBTQ
}
var=$(query_td)
echo $var

$ ksh varoutput.bt
2017/05/14
```

---

```
$ vi testoutput4.bt
testabcd=$(bteq <<EOF |grep '^>' |sed -e "s/^>//"
.LOGON TDPROD/userid,pass;

select top 3  '>'||t.cal_dt from rldmprod_v.cal_dt t where t.cal_dt =   current_date;

.LOGOFF;
.QUIT;
EOF)
var=$testabcd
echo $var

$ ksh testoutput4.bt
 *** Failure 5628 Column > not found in rldmprod_v.t.
            Statement# 1, Info =0
```

Comment: The `EOF` in the second code should be on a line by itself (i.e. not `EOF)`).

Answer (score 1):

The terminator of end of inline block (`EOF` in your case) must be the only string in the line. And your script should be rewrite on this manner:

```
testabcd=$(bteq <<EOF |grep '^>' |sed -e "s/^>//"
.LOGON TDPROD/userid,pass;

select top 3  '>'||t.cal_dt from rldmprod_v.cal_dt t where t.cal_dt =   current_date;

.LOGOFF;
.QUIT;
EOF
)
var=$testabcd
echo $var
```